# How can I do color quantization of images in Android?

Tags: android, colors, palette, android-palette

I want to reduce the color count of an image. Android provides a palette library to build palettes:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.Builder.html

But the Palette Builder only build the palette itself, but doesn't return the color mapping.

Is there a lower level Android library that can do color quantization? Or do I need to implement this myself?